# How would I use this in my html structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery and I don't want to end up doing the wrong thing, I've done everything else but, I'm stuck on this part. How do I hook this is up? I've tried using script tags, but I'm not sure if thats right.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.menu').dropit()
});
```

Ok I've done what you guys suggested, but it still does not seem to work.
Heres the full code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>




<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/jquery/script.js"></script>
<script src="dropit.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropit.css" type="text/css" />



<style> 
body
{
background:url("");
background-size:0px 0px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-top:40px;
}
</style>




<STYLE>
<!--
 a:hover{color:#c0c0c0;}
-->
</STYLE>


<style>
    .navLink {
    color: #000000;    
    text-decoration: none !important;}

ul
{
list-style-type:none;
font-size: SMALL;
font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: regular;}

li
{
display:inline;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>



<img border="0" src="http://az61389.vo.msecnd.net/6/_ui/img/mosaic/big-transparent-block.png" alt="Vealed" width="100" height="70">
<HR COLOR="#C0C0C0" WIDTH="100%">

<ul id="nav" >

<img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="450" height="1"> <li><a href="#">
     <a href="#">MENS</a>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jackets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Denim</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fleece</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>



<img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="30" height="1">  
         <li><a href="#" class="navLink">WOMEN'S</a></li>
<img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="30" height="1">
    <li><a href="#" class="navLink">NEW ARRIVALS</a>
<img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="30" height="1">
    <li><a href="#" class="navLink">BLOG</a>
<img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="30" height="1">
    <li><a href="#" class="navLink">SALE</a>
</ul>

<HR COLOR="#C0C0C0" WIDTH="100%">

<ul id="nav" >
<img border="0" src="http://az61389.vo.msecnd.net/6/_ui/img/mosaic/big-transparent-block.png" alt="Vealed" width="0" height="2">

<p><p align="center"><img border="0" src="http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/6192/5eo7.png" alt="Vealed" width="800" height="500">


<img border="0" src="http://az61389.vo.msecnd.net/6/_ui/img/mosaic/big-transparent-block.png" alt="Vealed" width="70" height="2">

</ul>







<img border="0" src="http://az61389.vo.msecnd.net/6/_ui/img/mosaic/big-transparent-block.png" alt="Vealed" width="100" height="200"



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.menu').dropit();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to make it so that all the links in the menu will have a drop down.

Comment: yes you use script tags but you also need to include a link to the jquery library

Comment: I have, but do I include this in the head or body?

Comment: The script src goes in the head. The script itself can go before the body

Answer (score 3):

Put the script tag in between your head tags like so

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

put this right before the closing body tag like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.menu').dropit();
});
</script>
</body>
```

---

Another option, instead of putting your jQuery code at the bottom, is to put all your javascript/jquery in a separate file. And then just link to it.

For example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfilename.js"></script>
</body>  //again, you put this right before the closing body tag
```

And then in your myjsfilename.js file, you would have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.menu').dropit();
});
```

plus anymore javascript/jquery code you want to add

Doing it that way can help keep things organized

Comment: I've done this, but it shows the actual text,  $(document).ready ,on the web page

Answer (score 2):

Add a script tag like this to the head or body of your html:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/jquery/script.js"></script>
```

as far as best practices go for where to add it, check here for a good discussion:

[Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

The first script tag above links to a CDN, and allows you to include jQuery without having to have it locally. This is a great way to do it as long as you dont include many external scripts. Once you have many scripts it would be better to include everything in a local minified file to increase page load performance.

Answer (score 1):

I drew a small diagram to help anyone understand the answers visually.

As a rule of thumb, I recommend putting all scripts at the bottom for performance issues.

It is a best practice, I'd say. So put your code before the `</body>` closes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.menu').dropit();
});
</script>
```

And obviously you need to load your jQuery from a CDN, so put it above all script code.

Yes, that would also need to go before the `</body>` closes.

The diagram explains it better now. Have a look.

[image]

Comment: @agconti: Bringing a new wave of using pictures and animation on SO :)